# My Windows partition got overlapped with Linux LVM

Tags: debian, partition, windows, lvm, parrotsec

So this happends when I want to setup dual-boot ParrotOS and Windows. When I want to install Parrot, I accidentally select 'use all disk and setup LVM' (not encripted) and I noticed that and click cancel but the LVM already been setup. Can I revert the LVM setup?

I checked my windows partition on ParrotOS live using TestDisk, the files are intact and I'm copying the files to removable flashdrive as a backup. Is there anything I can do to make my partition bootable inside LVM? or how can I extract the partition to direct partition not inside LVM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best, easy and fast you can do is to copy recovered files to external media and start installations (first Windows, then Linux) from scratch.

And this time when install linux use free diskspace, not entire disk

Comment: is there any other solution other then reinstalling windows? My primary workspace is on windows so is there any ways to remove the LVM without removing my windows partition? Thanks

Comment: @Edqe, you already remove windows partition. So you can try to recover it with some software. But because of creation of LVM I am not sure you will succeed to recover consistent filesystem with necessary files to run and work with Windows. And at the end you can spend more (much) time on recovering (eventually w/o success) compared to time of new installation and config your desktop.